# Approach to access server requirements for PHP app

Tags: looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

We're going to be launching an app that we believe will ultimately generate a couple thousand page views a day, but on day one it's gonna be close to zero.

What I'm trying to figure out is how we can access our minimum hosting requirements. 
It's a PHP app on the CodeIgniter framework that uses PrinceXML to produce PDFs.

Does it 'generally' make sense to start on virtual dedicated server rather than the cloud? Is there a way to access whether our server will need 2GB or 4GB things like that?

I can find my way around Plesk, but I have near zero experience with Linux or cloud hosting and trying to learn as much as I can before we launch/

Any advice as to the best way to approach this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I use media temple, like a number of similar providers, rackspace for example.

With a DV box from MT I can add additional RAM, processors, and disk space as needed (sub 1 hour lead time), I can even upgrade the plan on the fly to handle increases in traffic.